# Cell formatting excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to display a time exceeding 24 hours, I write in a cell format in the Type [h]: mm; @ field and I get an answer not 25 hours, but 241: 00 who faced a similar problem, please help me to solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: What was the exact value in the cell you have formatted?

Comment: @JvdV in the 1st cell the date with the format (date), in the second time (with the time format) in 3 the formula = CONCATENATE (C1; D1) - CONCATENATE (A1; B1) up to 24 counts as needed, but if above 24 it is already 241 etc

Comment: Without the data it's hard to tell what you are doing here. Instead of the formula or the outcome, please let us know the exact data you are having in those cells. Maybe give an example through a printscreen in your OP?

Comment: @JvdV I added pictures

Comment: Do you understand the concept of `CONCATENATE()`? Right now it will concatenate the `VALUE()` of `C1` which is 44385 and the fraction of an integer which is the time (0.86805...) into something like 443850.86805... Your method is completely of, hence why I said it's important to see the actual data you are working with =). Rather just use `=(C1+D1)-(A1+B1)`

Comment: @JvdV how to achieve the desired result?

Comment: @JvdV Submit as an answer and I will close this topic. Maybe someone will come in handy in the future, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment section; you are currently using `CONCATENATE()` to piece together integers (days) and fractions of those (time) into a string you weren't expecting, for example `=CONCATENATE(C1,D1)` results in `=CONCATENATE(44385,0.868055....)` which in return results in `443850.8...`, hence the extreme results you were facing.

Instead just use: `=(C1+D1)-(A1+B1)`